# MongoDB aggregate chain from matches

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, aggregate, aggregation

My targred is to exclude records which are already mateched from previous match aggregation in MongoDb.

In first match I need to fetch records from two countries: United States and Germany.

In second match I need to exclude records from given country, for example United States AND level of "Begginer", but keep other records from United States and Germany. How is that possible?
Example Data:

```
[
  {
    country: 'United States',
    personName: 'John',
    level: 'Average',
  },
  {
    country: 'United States',
    personName: 'Rina',
    level: 'Begginer',
  },
  {
    country: 'Germany',
    personName: 'John',
    level: 'Average',
  }
]
```

First match (correct):

```
{
  country: {$in: ['United States', 'Germany']}
}
```

Second match (wrong):

```
{
  $and: [
    { level: { $ne: 'Begginer'} },
    { country: { $eq: 'United States' } },
  ]
}
```

I do not want to add countries array again in second match phase.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll need an `$or` so that you keep all records that are not 'United States':

```js
db.stuff.aggregate([
  { $match: {
      country: {$in: ['United States', 'Germany'] }
    }
  },
  { $match: {
      $or: [
        { country: { $ne: 'United States' } },
        { country: { $eq: 'United States' }, level: { $ne: 'Begginer'} }
      ]
    }
  }
]);
```

You can then just combined the 2 matches in to one.

```js
db.stuff.aggregate([
  { $match: {
      country: {$in: ['United States', 'Germany'] },
      $or: [
        { country: { $ne: 'United States' } },
        { country: { $eq: 'United States' }, level: { $ne: 'Begginer'} }
      ]
    }
  }
]);
```

Both these queries will output:

```
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e999bdee125b211df7f361a"),
        "country" : "United States",
        "personName" : "John",
        "level" : "Average"
}
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e999bdee125b211df7f361c"),
        "country" : "Germany",
        "personName" : "John",
        "level" : "Average"
}
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/oXBqAzBHzUr

Comment: Those will remove my other records from United States

Comment: @IntoTheDeep sorry was click-happy, the above will we exactly for your scenario now 

Comment: What if I have 100 other countries? This is exactly what I am trying to avoid

Comment: Not sure I get what you mean? if you have 100 countries that you want to match on you'll have to pass them all in?

Comment: My target is to do a chain of matches in which every next match just exclude records from previous. Not to do int in a single match.

Comment: It will get optimised to be a single match statement in the db engine anyway? I don't really understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I don't want to be a single match because the data that will come will be relative. Meaning that countries can be 100 or no countries at all. My target is to add couple of matches which just exclude from previous.